# How can I reset network settings without a network connection?

Tags: raspbian, networking, dhcp

I have disabled DHCP on my Raspberry Pi and manually set up the `eth` network. The problem is that the network is no longer available and I want to re-enable DHCP. How can I reset the network configuration without network access to the Raspberry Pi?

OS is Raspbian Wheezy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can remove your memory card and place it in a Linux machine/laptop. Then go to the `/etc/network/interfaces` file in the memory card.

In that file you can again change the `eth0` to `dhcp` if you want.

I followed [this tutorial](http://www.penguintutor.com/linux/raspberrypi-headless) to get this done.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way would be to connect you Pi to a monitor and a keyboard.
Turn it on and configure it directly from the console.

Should you not have a keyboard or a mouse around (e.g. you only have a laptop), you could change your computer settings so that it *will* see the Pi.

For example if your Pi is on the 192.168.1.x network instead of 192.168.0.x, just change your laptop network settings to see the 192.168.1.x and give it an address that is different from the one you gave to the Pi, and enter via ssh. This requires cooperation from the router though.